# Matching String: cannot move out of borrowed content

Tags: rust

`req.url.fragment` is an optional `String`. If it has a value, I want to copy that value into `fragment`, otherwise I want to assign an empty string. I keep getting the error that I `cannot move out of borrowed content`.

How do I resolve this?

```
fn fb_token(req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let fragment = match req.url.fragment {
        Some(fragment) => fragment,
        None => "".to_string(),
    };

    Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, fragment)))
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the existing string in the structure.

```
let fragment = match req.url.fragment {
    Some(fragment) => fragment,
    None => "".to_string(),
};
```

In this code, you are *moving* the String out of `req.url.fragment`, but that would leave it in an undefined state. That's a bad thing, and Rust prevents you from doing that!

As the error message states:

> to prevent the move, use `ref fragment` or `ref mut fragment` to capture value by reference

If you want to leave the string where it is and return a copy, then you can take a reference and then clone it:

```
let fragment = match req.url {
    Some(ref fragment) => fragment.clone(),
    None => "".to_string()
};
```

If you want to leave the existing string as a `None`, then you can use `take`:

```
let fragment = match req.url.take() {
    Some(fragment) => fragment,
    None => "".to_string()
};
```

Even shorter, you can use `unwrap_or_else`:

```
let fragment = req.url.take().unwrap_or_else(String::new);
```

Comment: I did understand the thing about how borrowing freezes the referred object, meaning moving is not allowed in this case but I just couldn't figure out how to avoid the moving. Clearly I need to revise some concepts and go through the docs more carefully.  Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that one cannot invalidate a `&mut` reference, and moving ownership out is one way to invalidate. (There's a few links to similar questions/answers in the sidebar on the right.)

A fix is to instead use references, which should work quite well in this case:

```
fn fb_token(req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let fragment: &str = match req.url.fragment {
        Some(ref fragment) => &**fragment,
        None => "",
    };

    Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, fragment)))
}
```

(The `&str` annotation isn't necessary, just to make it clearer what's happening.)

This works because [iron implements `Modifier<Response>` for `&str`](https://github.com/iron/iron/blob/220b7a339501bcaa6a3f5200d00a428a9e098c2e/src/modifiers.rs#L77), so that type can be used with `with` instead of the owned `String`.