# How to use contains() and retain() with String?

Tags: iterator, rust

I'm trying to use the `retain(...)` method to filter out values from a vector. As it stands, my code thus far is

```
let results = get_data(); // Returns Result<Vec<MyData>, Box<Error>>

match results {
    Ok(mut my_data) => {

        // Make sure that `name` is not None
        myData.retain(|ref d| d.name.is_some());

        // Only keep data if 'name' is in this list
        let names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Claire"];
        my_data.retain(|ref d| names.contains(d.name.unwrap().as_str()));
    },
    Err(_) => {}
}
```

However, this yields the error

```
|
|     my_data.retain(|ref d| names.contains(d.name.unwrap().as_str()));
|                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected &str, found str
|
= note: expected type `&&str`
           found type `&str`
```

It seems like the compiler is telling me two separate things here, but in both cases it seems to want an additional reference. However, when I try to change the relevant line to `&names.contains(d.name.unwrap().as_str())`, the compiler throws the following error.

```
|
|     my_data.retain(|ref d| names.contains(&d.name.unwrap().as_str()));
|                                            ^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

How can I check whether a borrowed `String` (I think that's what the type of `name.unwrap()` is anyway) is contained in the `names` vector?

Comment: Please include the error's context, so we know where it's pointing to.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Ideally, produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org). Reduce your code as far as possible — do you *need* to return a `Result`; do you *need* a custom struct, do you *need* to have multiple `retain` statements, etc. Your code doesn't make sense: you say you have a `Result`, but your `match` statement uses `Result::Ok` and `Option::None`.

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, and fields and `UpperCamelCase` for types. Use `my_data` instead, please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a [MCVE](/help/mcve) of your problem (your original code has other, unrelated problems that are ignored here):

```
struct MyData {
    name: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_data: Vec<MyData> = vec![];

    // Only keep data if 'name' is in this list
    let names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Claire"];
    my_data.retain(|ref d| names.contains(d.name.unwrap().as_str()));
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:43
   |
10 |     my_data.retain(|ref d| names.contains(d.name.unwrap().as_str()));
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `&str`, found `str`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&&str`
              found reference `&str`
```

As the error message states, [`slice::contains`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.contains) requires a reference to the type of value contained in the slice:

```
pub fn contains(&self, x: &T) -> bool
where
    T: PartialEq<T>,
```

Since your slice contains string literals (of type `&'static str`), it needs a `&&str` to compare against. We will take a reference to the result of the `as_str` method:

```
my_data.retain(|ref d| names.contains(&d.name.unwrap().as_str()));
//                                    ^-- added
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `d.name` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:10:44
   |
10 |     my_data.retain(|ref d| names.contains(&d.name.unwrap().as_str()));
   |                                            ^^^^^^
   |                                            |
   |                                            move occurs because `d.name` has type `std::option::Option<std::string::String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                                            help: consider borrowing the `Option`'s content: `d.name.as_ref()`
```

This error is already thoroughly explained elsewhere on Stack Overflow:

- [Cannot move out of value which is behind a shared reference when unwrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32338659/155423)
- [Cannot move out of borrowed content / cannot move out of behind a shared reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28158738/155423)
- [Can't borrow File from &mut self (error msg: cannot move out of borrowed content)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28034646/155423)
- [Matching String: cannot move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29926724/155423)

TL;DR — you don't own `d`, so you cannot unwrap `d.name`, consuming the value in the process. The fix is to use [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref):

```
my_data.retain(|ref d| names.contains(&d.name.as_ref().unwrap().as_str()));
//                                           ^^^^^^^^^-- added
```

However, needing to `unwrap` is ugly and it's ideally avoided. You can combine the two `retain` calls into one *and* skip the unwrap by using [`Option::map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or):

```
my_data.retain(|d| {
    d.name.as_ref().map_or(false, |name| {
        let name = name.as_str();
        names.contains(&name)
    })
});
```

This removes a potential panic and improves the efficiency of the code.

Since Rust 1.40, this can be shortened with [`Option::as_deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref):

```
my_data.retain(|d| {
    d.name
        .as_deref()
        .map_or(false, |name| names.contains(&name))
});
```

See also:

- [Converting from Option<String> to Option<&str>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31233938/155423)